# Query help to subract the number from a string

Tags: shell-script

I am beginner to unix here I have a criteria I have a variable in that

- 1st variable `l_row_count_h` has count of 80 and I need to sutbract 1 from the `l_row_count_h` and get the result into another variable `l_row_count`.
- I wrote the script as

  ```
  l_row_count = ` expr $l_row_count_h - 1`
  ```

  but I get

  ```
  error: l_row_count: command not found
  ```

How can I eliminate the error?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the whitespace around the `=` sign

Answer (score 1):

Umm, try something like this?

```
echo $l_row_count_h
80

echo $(( l_row_count_h - 1 ))
79

l_row_count=$(( l_row_count_h - 1 ))

echo $l_row_count
79
```

Read about arithmetic in Bash **[here](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Perform_arithmetic_operations)**.